# How to script an animation based on 3d joint data?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, bones

*I have looked at the other questions that have been posted here and I am very sorry that this is such a similar question AGAIN but none of the issues solved it for my issue.*

I am working on an application that converts 3d joint positions into an animation with the goal of saving the deformed mesh at certain points.

What I have right now is a mesh, an armature that is properly parented to it (I checked in pose mode) and all the 3d joint positions. What I would like to do now is "just" move the heads and tails of the bones (in *edit/object/pose mode*, whichever gives me a deformed mesh to export) to the correct position with a python script and then export the deformed mesh.

However, while I can change the armature in *edit mode* by positioning heads and tails of the `edit_bones`, the mesh stays the same (duh) and in pose mode I can only set the location of the entire `pose_bone`, heads and tails are read only. I would like to avoid the hassle of computing translation matrices, rotation matrices and scale factors for every joint - am I missing something?

*It feels like I am so close to the solution and yet I can't progress.*

---

#### Code version 1

Code with pose mode (the way I understand it this should move all bones randomly but the actual result is it just moves the root node and and therefore the whole mesh, all joints stay in the same relative position to the root node. If I try to move only the nose for example nothing happens but the `pose_bone.location` changes, maybe I am missing the `bpy.context.scene.update()` from the example but it causes an attribute error for me) as per [this solution on stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111100/how-do-you-manipulate-pose-bones-using-python)

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
import mathutils
import random
from bpy import context

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
armature = bpy.context.scene.objects['Armature']

for pose_bone in armature.pose.bones:

    print(pose_bone.location)
    x = pose_bone.location[0] + random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)
    y = pose_bone.location[1] + random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)
    z = pose_bone.location[2] + random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)
    pose_bone.location[0] = x
    pose_bone.location[1] = y
    pose_bone.location[2] = z
    print(pose_bone.location)
    print('changed' + pose_bone.name)
```

Instead of directly assigning the coordinates i also tried this `bone.location = armature.matrix_world.inverted() @ bone.bone.matrix_local.inverted() @ v` in case there was an issue with coordinate systems but the result is the same, I cannot independently move individual bones.

Update on the pose mode solution: it seems like the issue was setting the location, this only works for my root node, the location change is ignored everywhere else (why is the functionality provided for non root bones then ?).

What *does* work is setting the rotation of individual bones but that brings me back to the problem that i would have to compute the rotation matrices (and potential scaling) for every frame of my data, which will probably result in errors at the ends of the limbs because of accumulating errors.

---

#### Code version 2

This version is in *Edit Mode* and changes heads and tails of the armature bones but the mesh remains unchanged (per [this solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31707/how-to-move-bones-rest-position-from-python))

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
import mathutils
import random as rd
from bpy import context

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
obj = context.object

for bone in obj.data.edit_bones:

    random_vector_1 = mathutils.Vector((rd.uniform(-0.2, 0.2), rd.uniform(-0.2, 0.2), rd.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)))
    bone.head += random_vector_1
    random_vector_2 = mathutils.Vector((rd.uniform(-0.2, 0.2), rd.uniform(-0.2, 0.2), rd.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)))
    bone.tail += random_vector_2
```

---

My data is not true mocap but `.cdf` (nasa, not wolfram alpha) so I have just raw 3d positions. Links to the similar issues: [1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3549/how-can-a-bones-tail-be-changed-by-a-script) [2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31707/how-to-move-bones-rest-position-from-python) [3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73914/move-bone-to-a-certain-location-python?rq=1) [4](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159829/how-to-move-a-bone-in-pose-mode-using-python?rq=1) [5](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115817/animate-rigged-character-using-3d-joint-location-coordinates?noredirect=1&lq=1) [6](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122369/create-animation-videos-from-3d-joint-positions) [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576501/why-the-mesh-didnt-follow-the-armature-in-the-edit-mode-how-to-get-the-coordin)

Comment: Please post the code you have so far as well as how the data look like and the links to *all the other questions* you've mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Consider setting up constraints pose bones to empties. Eg a forearm bone could track to the wrist joint.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30835/convert-a-c3d-and-trc-files-to-bvh

Comment: @batFINGER unfortunately my data is not true mocap but .cdf (nasa, not wolfram aplpha) so i have just raw 3d positions. i will however look into the issue, thank you

Comment: @batFINGER i have not used constraints yet, how could they help me to move the heads and tails of the pose bones to a specific 3d location ? would it be like this (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79344/move-bone-tail-to-a-certain-location) ?

Comment: See the link posted above.  The input data was hierarchical empties from a c3d or trc file. Both answers explain how the constraints are set up.  Your question code is all about moving pose bones (or edit bones).  What is prob of more interest to solve this is the data and its format. Are they just globally located empties or is there some parent structure to them?

Comment: @batFINGER My data is basically just a very big float matrix of shape [numbarOfFrames, 93], for each of the 31 mocap points 3 coordinates. Unfortunately I cant share any of it as it is part of the Human3.6M dataset and not allowed. The reason i am going this route is that initially i just wanted to take the mesh they provide, rig it and then animate it by just transforming the pose bones so they align with my 3d data points. But I guess maybe it makes more sense to go the route like the dog example, build the armature based on the initial 3d positions and then fit a mesh around it somehow.

Comment: @batFINGER i have repurposed the dog example and it seems to be going well, thank you very much for the help. only thing that remains now is adding a mesh and exporting it somehow.

Comment: I have been able to do this. Perhaps the problem is that you need to persist the changes by switching to OBJECT mode.